# How to update my view when I click search button in Android app?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm currently learning Android programming. My task is to update view after clicking "search button" in the menu (onCreateOptionsMenu method).

Should I kill thread "ThumbnailDownloader" and start new one to update the view. Or maybe should I add listener to mPhotoRecyclerView? It's also could be something with cache. I don't realy know. Any advice or solution would be very helpful.

```
package com.bignerdranch.photogallery;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PhotoGalleryFragment extends Fragment{

    private static final String TAG = "PhotoGalleryFragment";
    private RecyclerView mPhotoRecyclerView;
    private TextView          mCurrentPageText;
    private List<GalleryItem> mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private int pageFetched = 0;
    private GridLayoutManager mGridManager;
    boolean asyncFetching   = false;
    int     mCurrentPage    = 1;
    int     mMaxPage        = 1;
    int     mItemsPerPage   = 1;
    int     mFirstItemPosition, mLastItemPosition;
    private ThumbnailDownloader<Integer> mThumbnailDownloader;


    public static Fragment newInstance() {
    return new PhotoGalleryFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        updateItems();

        Handler responseHandler = new Handler();
        mThumbnailDownloader = new ThumbnailDownloader<>(responseHandler);
        mThumbnailDownloader.setThumbnailDownloadListener(
                new ThumbnailDownloader.ThumbnailDownloadListener<Integer>() { //chanched to Integer
                    @Override
                    public void onThumbnailDownloaded(Integer position, Bitmap bitmap) {

                        mPhotoRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(position);

                    }
                }
        );
        mThumbnailDownloader.start();
        mThumbnailDownloader.getLooper();
        Log.i(TAG, "Background thread started");

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo_gallery, container, false);
        mCurrentPageText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.currentPageText);

        mPhotoRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.photo_recycler_view);


        mPhotoRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
              //  Context context;
                float columnWidthInPixels = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 140, getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                int width = mPhotoRecyclerView.getWidth();
                int columnNumber = Math.round(width / columnWidthInPixels);
                mGridManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3);
                mPhotoRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridManager);
                mPhotoRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mCurrentPage);
                mPhotoRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });

        mPhotoRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                int lastVisibleItem = mGridManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                int firstVisibleItem = mGridManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if (mLastItemPosition != lastVisibleItem || mFirstItemPosition != firstVisibleItem) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Showing item " + firstVisibleItem +" to " + lastVisibleItem);
                    updatePageText(firstVisibleItem);

                    mLastItemPosition  = lastVisibleItem;
                    mFirstItemPosition = firstVisibleItem;
                    int begin = Math.max(firstVisibleItem-10,0              );
                    int end   = Math.min(lastVisibleItem +10,mItems.size()-1);
                    for (int position = begin; position <= end; position++){
                        String url=mItems.get(position).getUrl();
                        if(mThumbnailDownloader.mPhotoCache.get(url)== null) {
                            Log.d(TAG,"Requesting Download at position: "+ position);
                            mThumbnailDownloader.queueThumbnail(position,url);
                        }

                    }
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "Scrolling, First Item: "+ firstVisibleItem + " Last item: " + lastVisibleItem);

                if(!(asyncFetching) && (dy>0)&&(mCurrentPage<mMaxPage)&& (lastVisibleItem>=(mItems.size()-1))){
                    Log.d(TAG, "Fetching more");
                   updateItems();

                } else updatePageText(firstVisibleItem);

            }
        });

        if(mPhotoRecyclerView.getAdapter() == null)setupAdapter();
        return v;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView(){
        super.onDestroyView();
        mThumbnailDownloader.clearQueue();
        mThumbnailDownloader.clearCache();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        mThumbnailDownloader.quit();
        Log.i(TAG, "Background thread destroyed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater){
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, menuInflater);
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.fragmen_photo_gallery, menu);

        final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search);
        final  SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "QueryTextSubmit: " + s);
                QueryPreferences.setStoredQuery(getActivity(), s);


                updateItems();




                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "QueryTextChange: " +s);
                return false;
            }
        });

        searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String query = QueryPreferences.getStoredQuery(getActivity());
                searchView.setQuery(query, false);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menu_item_clear:
                QueryPreferences.setStoredQuery(getActivity(), null);
                updateItems();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void updateItems(){
        String query = QueryPreferences.getStoredQuery(getActivity());
        new FetchItemsTask(query).execute();




    }

    private  void updatePageText(int pos){
        mCurrentPage = pos / mItemsPerPage+1;
        mCurrentPageText.setText("Page " + mCurrentPage + " of " + mMaxPage);
    }

    private void setupAdapter(){
        if(isAdded()){
            mPhotoRecyclerView.setAdapter(new PhotoAdapter(mItems));
        }
    }

    private class PhotoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private  ImageView mItemImageView;

        public PhotoHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);

            mItemImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image_view);
        }

        public void bindDrawable (Drawable drawable){
        mItemImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable); }
    }

    private class PhotoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotoHolder>{

        private List<GalleryItem> mGalleryItems;

        public PhotoAdapter(List<GalleryItem> galleryItems){
            mGalleryItems = galleryItems;
        }


        @NonNull
        @Override
        public PhotoHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
            Context context;
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, viewGroup, false);
return new PhotoHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PhotoHolder photoHolder, int position) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Binding item "+ position + " to " + photoHolder.hashCode());
            GalleryItem galleryItem = mGalleryItems.get(position);
            String url              = galleryItem.getUrl();
            Bitmap bitmap           = mThumbnailDownloader.mPhotoCache.get(url);
            if(bitmap == null) {
                Drawable placeholder = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
                photoHolder.bindDrawable(placeholder);
            }else {
                Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
                photoHolder.bindDrawable(drawable);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mGalleryItems.size();
        }
    }

    private class FetchItemsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<GalleryItem>>{
        private String mQuery;

        public FetchItemsTask(String query){
            mQuery = query;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<GalleryItem> doInBackground(Void...params){
           asyncFetching = true;

            if(mQuery == null){
                return new FlickrFetch().fetchRecentPhotos(pageFetched+1);
            } else{

                return new FlickrFetch().searchPhotos(mQuery, pageFetched+1);
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<GalleryItem>items){
         pageFetched++;
         asyncFetching=false;
         mItems.addAll(items);
         GalleryPage pge = GalleryPage.getGalleryPage();
         mMaxPage = pge.getTotalPages();
         mItemsPerPage = pge.getItemPerPage();

         if(mPhotoRecyclerView.getAdapter()==null)setupAdapter();
         mPhotoRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            updatePageText(mGridManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in onPostExecute method in the very end of the class.

I deleted

```
mItems.addAll(items);
```

and added

```
mItems = items;
            setupAdapter();
```

Now it works fine.